# Find mouse pos in 3D space?

Tags: java, 3d, tilemap, transformation, processing

I have a game where there is a set of tiles rotated 45° away from the camera. I want to work out what tile is being hovered over by the mouse, and for that I need to translate the mouse pos on the screen into the position on the plane rotated 45° away. How can I do this? Is there an easy way of doing this without using (expensive) 3D transformation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the projection orthographic or perspective?

Comment: Perspective, but I can change if it makes it super hard @Turms